# Difference between apply() and apply_async() in Python multiprocessing module

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I currently have a piece of code which spawns multiple processes as follows:

```
pool = Pool(processes=None)
results = [pool.apply(f, args=(arg1, arg2, arg3)) for arg3 in arg_list]
```

My idea was that this would divide the work across cores, using all cores available since `processes=None`. However, the documentation for the `Pool.apply()` method in the [multiprocessing module docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) reads:

> Equivalent of the apply() built-in function. It blocks until the result is ready, so apply_async() is better suited for performing work in parallel. Additionally, func is only executed in one of the workers of the pool.

**First question:**
I don't clearly understand this. How does `apply` distribute the work across workers, and in what way is it different from what `apply_async` does? If the tasks get distributed across workers, how is it possible that `func` is only executed in one of the workers?

**My guess**: my guess would be that the `apply`, in my current implementation, is giving a task to a worker with a certain set of arguments, then waiting for that worker to be done, and then giving the next set of arguments to another worker. In this way I am sending work to different processes, yet **no parallelism is taking place**. This seems to be the case since `apply` is in fact just:

```
def apply(self, func, args=(), kwds={}):
    '''
    Equivalent of `func(*args, **kwds)`.
    Pool must be running.
    '''
    return self.apply_async(func, args, kwds).get()
```

**Second question:** I would also like to understand better why, in the introduction of the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction), section 16.6.1.5. ('Using a pool of workers'), they say that even a construction with `apply_async` such as
   `[pool.apply_async(os.getpid, ()) for i in range(4)]`
*may* use more processes, but it isn't sure that it will. **What decides whether multiple processes will be used?**

Comment: [related1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54757400/9059420), [related2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53035293/9059420)

Answer (score 10):

You have pointed to a Python2.7 documentation so I'm going to base my answers on Python2.7 multiprocessing implementation. It might differ on Python3.X but should not be very different.

### Difference between `apply` and `apply_async`

Difference between these two is really self describing when you view how those are actually implemented underneath. Here I'm going to copy/paste code from `multiprocessing/pool.py` for bot functions.

```
def apply(self, func, args=(), kwds={}):
    '''
    Equivalent of `apply()` builtin
    '''
    assert self._state == RUN
    return self.apply_async(func, args, kwds).get()
```

As you can see, `apply` is actually calling `apply_async` but just before returning result, `get` is called. This basically makes `apply_async` block until result is returned.

```
def apply_async(self, func, args=(), kwds={}, callback=None):
    '''
    Asynchronous equivalent of `apply()` builtin
    '''
    assert self._state == RUN
    result = ApplyResult(self._cache, callback)
    self._taskqueue.put(([(result._job, None, func, args, kwds)], None))
    return result
```

`apply_async` enqueues task in task queue, and returns a `handle` of submitted task. With that `handle` you can call `get` or `wait` to get the results or wait for task to finish, respectively. After task is finished, what it returns gets passed as an argument to `callback` function.

#### Example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import sleep


def callback(a):
    print a


def worker(i, n):
    print 'Entering worker ', i
    sleep(n)
    print 'Exiting worker'
    return 'worker_response'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(4)
    a = [pool.apply_async(worker, (i, 4), callback=callback) for i in range(8)]
    for i in a:
        i.wait()
```

#### Results:

```
Entering worker  0
Entering worker  1
Entering worker  2
Entering worker  3
Exiting worker
Exiting worker
Exiting worker
Exiting worker
Entering worker  4
Entering worker  5
worker_response
Entering worker  6
worker_response
Entering worker  7
worker_response
worker_response
Exiting worker
Exiting worker
Exiting worker
Exiting worker
worker_response
worker_response
worker_response
worker_response
```

Pay attention that, when using `apply_async`, you have to wait for results or wait for tasks to finish. If you do not i.e. comment last 2 lines of my example, your script will immediately finish after you run it.

### Why `apply_async` may use more processes

I understand this in regard to how `apply` is described and working. Since `apply` runs task by task sending it to available process in a `Pool`, `apply_async` adds tasks to queue and then tasks queue thread sends them to available processes in `Pool`. This is why more than one process may run when you use `apply_async`.

I went through [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) section couple of times to better understand the idea that author tried to convey. Lets check it here:

```
# evaluate "os.getpid()" asynchronously
res = pool.apply_async(os.getpid, ()) # runs in *only* one process
print res.get(timeout=1)              # prints the PID of that process

# launching multiple evaluations asynchronously *may* use more processes
multiple_results = [pool.apply_async(os.getpid, ()) for i in range(4)]
print [res.get(timeout=1) for res in multiple_results]
```

If we try to understand last example by looking at previous one, when you have multiple successive calls of `apply_async` it certainly **may** run more of them at the same time. This probably depends on how many processes in the `Pool` is used at that moment. That is why they say **may**.

Comment: why `apply_async().get` is little faster than `apply()`? `[pool.apply(os.getpid, ()) for i in range(4)]` uses the same process number.

Comment: It should say: "launching multiple evaluations asynchronously *may* use more than one of the pool's processes"