# Parallel Program error during pool creation in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

this is the first time I am using the parallel program in python, my program is shown below:

```
np.random.RandomState(100)
arr = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=[200000, 5])#print(arr)
data = arr.tolist()
data[:5]

def howmany_within_range(row, minimum, maximum):    
count = 0
for n in row:
    if minimum <= n <= maximum:
        count = count + 1
return count

pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
results = [pool.apply(howmany_within_range, args=(row, 4, 8)) for row in data]
pool.close()
print(results[:10])
```

the execution of this program give the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 114, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 225, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 277, in _fixup_main_from_path
    run_name="**mp_main**")
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\109_personel\113_ARIMA_Tmin\Test_2.py", line 24, in 
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 119, in Pool
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    context=self.get_context())
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 176, in **init**
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 114, in _main
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 241, in _repopulate_pool
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 225, in prepare
    w.start()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 112, in start
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
      File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 277, in _fixup_main_from_path
self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    run_name="**mp_main**")
    return Popen(process_obj)  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path

File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 33, in **init**
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 143, in get_preparation_data
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 136, in _check_not_importing_main
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.''')
RuntimeError: 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

```
    This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
    child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
    in the main module:

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            freeze_support()
            ...

    The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
exec(code, run_globals)
```

any one can help me to solve this error will be appreciated.

Comment: The solution is right in front of you. Add `if __name__ == '__main__':` like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52693952/9059420).  Also `pool.apply` won't help you here, [see](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53035293/9059420) and docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiprocessing pool example does not work and freeze the kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52693216/multiprocessing-pool-example-does-not-work-and-freeze-the-kernel)

Comment: Any code that is not protected by `if __name__ == '__main__':`, gets executed again when a new process is started (the new process imports your code).

Comment: Thank You all, my problem is solved:)