# Parallel execution of a list of functions

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

So using the multiprocess module it is easy to run a function in parallel with different arguments like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x**2


p = Pool(2)
print(p.map(f, [1, 2]))
```

But I'm interested in executing a list of functions on the same argument. Suppose I have the following two functions:

```
def f(x):
    return x**2


def g(x):
    return x**3 + 2
```

How can I execute them in parallel for the same argument (e.g. x=1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Pool.apply_async()` for that. You bundle up tasks in the form of (function, argument_tuple) and feed every task to `apply_async()`.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from itertools import repeat


def f(x):
    for _ in range(int(50e6)): # dummy computation
        pass
    return x ** 2


def g(x):
    for _ in range(int(50e6)): # dummy computation
        pass
    return x ** 3


def parallelize(n_workers, functions, arguments):
    # if you need this multiple times, instantiate the pool outside and
    # pass it in as dependency to spare recreation all over again
    with Pool(n_workers) as pool:
        tasks = zip(functions, repeat(arguments))
        futures = [pool.apply_async(*t) for t in tasks]
        results = [fut.get() for fut in futures]
    return results


if __name__ == '__main__':

    N_WORKERS = 2

    functions = f, g
    results = parallelize(N_WORKERS, functions, arguments=(10,))
    print(results)
```

Example Output:

```
[100, 1000]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a tuple returned. This could be done quite easily and in a very compact way using the lightweight module: joblib. I recommend joblib because it is lightweight

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing
import timeit


# Implementation 1
def f(x):    
    return x**2, x**3 + 2


#Implementation 2 for a more sophisticated second or more functions
def g(x):
    return  x**3 + 2


def f(x):    
    return x**2, g(x)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  inputs = [i for i in range(32)]
  num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
  t1 = timeit.Timer()
  result = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(f)(i) for i in inputs)
  print(t1.timeit(1))
```

Using multiprocessing.Pool as you already have in the question

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
import timeit


def g(x):
    return x**3 + 2


def f(x):    
    return x**2, g(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  inputs = [i for i in range(32)]
  num_cores = cpu_count()
  p = Pool(num_cores)
  t1 = timeit.Timer()
  result = p.map(f, inputs)
  print(t1.timeit(1))
  print(result)
```

Example Output:

```
print(result)

[(0, 2), (1, 3), (4, 10), (9, 29), (16, 66), (25, 127), (36, 218), (49, 345), 
(64, 514), (81, 731), (100, 1002), (121, 1333), (144, 1730), (169, 2199), 
(196, 2746), (225, 3377), (256, 4098), (289, 4915), (324, 5834), (361, 6861), 
(400, 8002), (441, 9263), (484, 10650), (529, 12169), (576, 13826), (625, 
15627), (676, 17578), (729, 19685), (784, 21954), (841, 24391), (900, 27002), 
(961, 29793)]

print(t1.timeit(1))
    5.000001692678779e-07         #(with 16 cpus and 64 Gb RAM)
```

for: inputs = range(2000), it took the time:
1.100000190490391e-06