# 2 methods running in Pool with same Input Values shows no multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-3.7

I am trying to understand how 2 methods can be executed in parallel using a simple and dumbed down example.  The issue is with respect to the execution results.  I observe that the execution happens in sequential order where the method `threeCheck()` is executed in its entirety before `sevenCheck()` is even called.
But my understanding was that both the methods would be executed in parallel.

- `threeCheck()` is a method that checks if a number is divisible by 3
- `sevenCheck()` is a method that checks if a number is divisible by 7
- I have added a random sleep duration in the method calls to mimic
  latency.

I see that the inputs passed into `threeCheck()` Method are being processed in parallel.  If we follow sequence, the numbers in the array divisible by 3 are : 
`84, 66, 60, 66, 87, 99, 42, .......`
But when we observe the execution results, the sequence shows otherwise for these first results

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import random

def threeCheck(inputParam):
    if inputParam % 3 == 0:
        duration = random.randint(0,6)
        print("3 INPUT = {0} and Sleep = {1}".format(inputParam, duration))
        time.sleep(duration)
        return inputParam

def sevenCheck(inputParam):
    if inputParam % 7 == 0:
        duration = random.randint(0,6)
        print("7 INPUT = {0} and Sleep = {1}".format(inputParam, duration))
        time.sleep(duration)
        return inputParam

def main():
    cpuCount = mp.cpu_count()
    pool = mp.Pool(cpuCount)
    inputValues = []
    for i in range(50):
        inputValues.append(random.randint(0,100))

    resultThree = pool.map(threeCheck, inputValues)
    resultSeven = pool.map(sevenCheck, inputValues)

    print("INPUT = ", inputValues)
    print("CPU = ", cpuCount)
    print("RESULT 3 = ", resultThree)
    print("RESULT 7 = ", resultSeven)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
OUTPUT:
3 INPUT = 84 and Sleep = 5
3 INPUT = 66 and Sleep = 2
3 INPUT = 60 and Sleep = 1
3 INPUT = 99 and Sleep = 3
3 INPUT = 66 and Sleep = 3
3 INPUT = 42 and Sleep = 5
3 INPUT = 12 and Sleep = 1
3 INPUT = 87 and Sleep = 6
3 INPUT = 57 and Sleep = 5
3 INPUT = 42 and Sleep = 3
3 INPUT = 30 and Sleep = 2
3 INPUT = 63 and Sleep = 0
3 INPUT = 42 and Sleep = 6
3 INPUT = 24 and Sleep = 2
3 INPUT = 21 and Sleep = 6
3 INPUT = 30 and Sleep = 4
3 INPUT = 27 and Sleep = 0
7 INPUT = 7 and Sleep = 1
7 INPUT = 84 and Sleep = 6
7 INPUT = 42 and Sleep = 6
7 INPUT = 28 and Sleep = 1
7 INPUT = 21 and Sleep = 6
7 INPUT = 42 and Sleep = 5
7 INPUT = 63 and Sleep = 3
7 INPUT = 91 and Sleep = 5
7 INPUT = 42 and Sleep = 6
INPUT =  [7, 95, 25, 19, 59, 82, 47, 68, 20, 76, 84, 8, 88, 29, 1, 66, 60, 66, 87, 25, 23, 80, 52, 99, 65, 65, 25, 42, 12, 38, 28, 88, 57, 21, 27, 40, 42, 38, 31, 91, 30, 68, 22, 24, 63, 42, 64, 17, 65, 30]
CPU =  4
RESULT 3 =  [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 84, None, None, None, None, 66, 60, 66, 87, None, None, None, None, 99, None, None, None, 42, 12, None, None, None, 57, 21, 27, None, 42, None, None, None, 30, None, None, 24, 63, 42, None, None, None, 30]
...
```

I am sure that I am missing something here ..

Comment: `Pool.map()` is blocking, so your understanding here was indeed wrong and the observed behaviour is what you should expect. Only the work _within_ the `.map()` call gets parallelized. If you need **two different** functions parallelized, you need to use [Pool.apply_async()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async) instead ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56076681/9059420)).

Comment: The other mystery, about unexpected ordering, is caused by chunking. You can read about this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53751050/9059420).

Comment: thanks @Darkonaut
this was really helpful ..