# why is more than one worker used in `multiprocessing.Pool().apply_async()`?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

**Problem**

From the `multiprocessing.Pool` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply):

> `apply_async(func ...)`: **A variant of the `apply()` method** which returns a result object. ...

Reading further ...

> `apply(func[, args[, kwds]])`: Call func with arguments args and keyword arguments kwds. It blocks until the result is ready. Given this blocks, apply_async() is better suited for performing work in parallel. **Additionally, func is only executed in one of the workers of the pool.**

The last bold line suggests only one worker from a pool is used. I find this is only true under certain conditions.

**Given**

Here is code that executes `Pool.apply_async()` in three similar cases.  In all cases, the process id is printed.

```
import os
import time
import multiprocessing as mp


def blocking_func(x, delay=0.1):
    """Return a squared argument after some delay."""
    time.sleep(delay)                                  # toggle comment here
    return x*x, os.getpid()


def apply_async():
    """Return a list applying func to one process with a callback."""
    pool = mp.Pool()
    # Case 1: From the docs
    results = [pool.apply_async(os.getpid, ()) for _ in range(10)]
    results = [res.get(timeout=1) for res in results]
    print("Docs    :", results)

    # Case 2: With delay
    results = [pool.apply_async(blocking_func, args=(i,)) for i in range(10)]
    results = [res.get(timeout=1)[1] for res in results]
    print("Delay   :", results)

    # Case 3: Without delay
    results = [pool.apply_async(blocking_func, args=(i, 0)) for i in range(10)]
    results = [res.get(timeout=1)[1] for res in results]
    print("No delay:", results)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    apply_async()
```

**Results**

The example from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) (Case 1) confirms only one worker is run.  We extend this example in the next cases by applying `blocking_func`, which blocks  with some delay.

Commenting the `time.sleep()` line in `blocking_func()` brings all cases in agreement.

```
# Time commented
# 1. Docs    : [8208, 8208, 8208, 8208, 8208, 8208, 8208, 8208, 8208, 8208]
# 2. Delay   : [8208, 8208, 8208, 8208, 8208, 8208, 8208, 8208, 8208, 8208]
# 3. No delay: [8208, 8208, 8208, 8208, 8208, 8208, 8208, 8208, 8208, 8208]
```

Each call to `apply_async()` creates a new process pool, which is why new process ids differ from the latter.

```
# Time uncommented
# 1. Docs    : [6780, 6780, 6780, 6780, 6780, 6780, 6780, 6780, 6780, 6780]
# 2. Delay   : [6780, 2112, 6780, 2112, 6780, 2112, 6780, 2112, 6780, 2112]
# 3. No delay: [6780, 2112, 6780, 2112, 6780, 2112, 6780, 2112, 6780, 2112]
```

However when `time.sleep()` is uncommented, even with zero delay, more than one worker is used.

In short, uncommented we expect one worker as in Case 1, but we get multiple workers as in Cases 2 and 3.

**Question**

Although I expect only one worker to be used by `Pool().apply_async()`, why are more than one used when `time.sleep()` is uncommented?  Should blocking even effect the number of workers used by `apply` or `apply_async`?

Note: previous, related questions ask "why is only one worker used?"  This question asks the opposite - "why *isn't* only one worker used?"  I'm using 2 cores on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your confusion seems to come from thinking `[pool.apply_async(...) for i in range(10)]` is ***one*** call, when there are really **ten** independent calls. A call to any pool-method is a "job". A job generally can lead to one or multiple tasks being distributed. `apply`-methods always produce only a single task under the hood. A task is an indivisible unit of work which will be received as a whole by a random pool-worker.

There's only one shared `inqueue`, all workers are fed over. Which idling worker will be woken up from waiting to `get()` a task from that queue is up to the OS. Your result-entropy for case 1 is still somewhat surprising and probably very lucky, at least unless you confirm you have only two cores.

And yes, your observation for this run is also influenced by the computation time needed for a task,  since threads (the scheduled execution unit within a process) usually are scheduled with time slicing policies (e.g. ~20ms for Windows).

Comment: Thanks. No I realize there are ten calls of `apply_async()`. What was unclear is that each call pertains to a random process selected from the pool of workers. The results led me to believe only one process was ever used, but this may have been a fluke since, yes, I only have two cores and the jobs may not have been intense enough to trigger process switching. – pylang 8 mins ago

Comment: @pylang Ah I see. The processes are created when you instantiate the Pool. So there were two processes, but only one happend to be scheduled in the blink it took to process your jobs.

Answer (score 2):

Only one worker is used *for that call*. A single `apply_async` cannot be executed in two workers. That doesn't prevent multiple `apply_async` calls from being executed in different workers. Such a restriction would run completely counter to the point of having a process pool at all.

Comment: Thanks.  I was not aware that a more than one worker can be used per call.  Why is only one process used in `Case 1`? Is the task not heavy enough to merit using more processes?

Answer (score 1):

Spurred by @Darkonaut's comment, I inspected further and observed the blocking function was too fast.  I tested the latter code, modified, with a new intensive blocking function.

**Code**

The new blocking function iteratively computes Fibonacci numbers.  An optional argument can be passed in to broaden the range and compute larger numbers.

```
def blocking_func(n, offset=0):
    """Return an intensive result via Fibonacci number."""
    n += offset
    a, b = 0, 1
    for _ in range(n):
        a, b = b, a + b
    return a, os.getpid()


def blocking_func(n, offset=0):
    """Return an intensive result via recursive fibonacci number."""
    func = blocking_func
    n += offset
    if n <= 1:
        return n, os.getpid()
    return func(n-1) + func(n-2)
```

```
if __name__ == '__main__':        
    start = time.time()
    apply_async()
    end = time.time()
    print(f"Duration : {end - start:.2f}s")
```

**Demo**

Passing in a large integer (`100000`) to the offset parameter, e.g. `...[pool.apply_async(blocking_func, args=(i, 100000)) ...]` and running the code, we are more reliably able to trigger process switching.

```
# Results
Docs     : [10032, 10032, 10032, 10032, 10032, 10032, 10032, 10032, 10032, 10032]
Offset   : [10032, 8268, 10032, 8268, 10032, 8268, 10032, 8268, 10032, 8268]
Duration : 1.67s
```

It's intriguing to note that 100k Fibonacci numbers are asynchronously being computed 10 times in less than 2 seconds.  By contrast, using a recursive implementation of Fibonacci would be comparably intensive at ~30 iterations (not shown).